# Python: Fastest way to count words and filter words with low occurrence

Tags: python, performance, filter, counter

I'm trying to find a very efficient way to filter rare words. This code takes currently 11 seconds with a 2D list of dimension 10000 x 28.

Any Idea how I could improve the performance of this task?

```
def remove_rare_terms(cluster_word_list):
   flatten_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cluster_word_list))
   filter_terms = [key for key, val in Counter(flatten_list).items() if val == 1]
   filter_terms_set = set(filter_terms)
   return [[k for k in cluster_word if k not in filter_terms_set] for cluster_word in cluster_word_list]
```

```
len(cluster_word_list)
> 10000
cluster_word_list[0:2]
> [['buzz', 'woody', 'andy', 'toy', 'lightyear', 'aside', 'afraid', 'onto', 'duo', 'happily', 'difference', 'circumstance', 'birthday', 'separate', 'room', 'brings', 'scene', 'learns', 'owner', 'eventually', 'plot', 'heart', 'put', 'place', 'lose', 'live', 'lead', 'story'], 
   ['game', 'alan', 'jumanji', 'rhinoceros', 'risky', 'enchant', 'monkey', 'judy', 'unwittingly', 'sibling', 'finish', 'magical', 'prof', 'terrify', 'door', 'board', 'freedom', 'adult', 'invite', 'giant', 'inside', 'peter', 'room', 'creature', 'trap', 'open', 'hope', 'evil', 'discover', 'living']]
```

Comment: Are you sure about these numbers? I created random testdata and run your function for 10000 lines * 30 words * 23 characters. It takes only around 150 ms. What is your count for the total number of characters? You can get that count with `len("".join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cluster_word_list)))`

Answer (score 1):

You flatten list length is 280,000. You want to minimize the number of time you iterate over it.

In your code, you have iterate about 5 times.
1) build the flatten list
2) build Counter(flatten_list)
3) build filter_terms
4) build filter_terms_set 
5) return statement

Technically, 3 and 4 are shorter as it only contains rare terms.
For your purpose, you only need to iterate twice. One at building counter and one at filtering rare terms.

Counter take iterators as input, you don't need to build the list. Membership check speed for Counter(dict) type is close to set, there is no need to build filter terms set too.

```
def remove_rare_terms(cluster_word_list):

    counter = Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cluster_word_list))
    return [[k for k in cluster_word if counter[k] ==1] for cluster_word in cluster_word_list]
```